# Android RecyclerView scaling problems

Tags: android, xml

I've been working on a project for quite a while now and I am almost done with it except for one small problem I couldn't solve myself. So in the program you can order products and at the end, you get a small AlertDialog to review your order one final time before submitting it.

The mentioned AlertDialog should contain a RecyclerView with all the ordered products and two buttons. It *should* look like this:

[How it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnFFL.png)

But when my RecyclerAdapter adds more than 2 products, the RecyclerView just grows and the Buttons begin shrinking. After 4 products the buttons are completely gone.

[How it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvhB8.png)

This is the XML attached to the AlertDialog, which gets inflated by a LayoutInflater:

[XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0lYE.png)

For the RecyclerViews LayoutManager I just used the default "LinearLayoutManager".

I understand ***why*** it is happening and why the buttons get shrunken, however I couldn't really figure out a way to make it work like I want: the buttons should have a fixed size that gets respected by the RecyclerView and if it would need to shrink the buttons then the RecyclerView would just not do it and stay in its current size so that the user needs to scroll.

Thanks for your help already and I hope we can get this running ✌️

Comment: either use weight property or set your recyleview height constant

Comment: @Manjeetdeswal the weight property didn't work as the buttons resized when the size of the recyclerview expanded and setting the height constant also didnt work, because then the RecyclerAdapter didnt fill out the entire width of the AlertDialog. I've already fixed it, tho, with the solution from Jorge Pastor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/constraint-layout) you can set `layout_constrainedHeight` in your `RecyclerView`.

```kotlin
implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/completeorder_mainlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/completeorder_finalizedorder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/buttons"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/completeorder_cancelbutton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="45"
            android:text="Zurück" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/completeorder_completeorderbutton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="65"
            android:text="Bestellung\nabschicken" />
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```